# How to add status for each user?

Tags: class, symfony, php-5.4

I have two entity doctor and status, every doctor can add many status, I have this code:

```
private function createCreateForm(statut $entity)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new statutType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('statut_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Ajouter'));

    return $form;
}.
```

This is status form:

```
$builder
    ->add('medecin', 'entity', array('class'=>'DoctorBundle:medecin', 'property'=>'id', 'multiple'=>false))
    ->add('text')
    ->add('description')
    ->add('image',new ImageType())
    ;`
```

Comment: my question is how the doctor can add his proper statut thanks ?

Comment: its a forum only to post a questions ? no answer ?

Comment: Try editing your question to include the actual question, instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Hi Aymen. Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a bit unclear what you're asking for. Can you provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i don't want that the choice field appear and the status must take id doctor from the doctor who want to add.